# sitecore extranet create user

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

I'm trying to create an extranet user within sitecore but i'm having issues.  I'm using the command Membership.CreateUser(username, password, email)

Nothing seems to happen though.  No user is created in the extranet aspnetdb.  No exceptions are thrown.

I also tried putting the domain as part of the user name: domain\username...and I get the error "You must specify a non-autogenerated machine key to store passwords in encrypted format.  Either specify a different passwordFormat, or change the machineKey configuration to use a non-autogenerated decryption key.".  My passwordFormat is Encrypted.

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try what the error message suggested? I would try setting your own Machine Key. More [about that here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). As always, do this in a test/dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code -

uname = string.Format(@"{0}{1}", domain, userName);
Membership.CreateUser(uname, password, email);